# Firebase logging out certain users unwarranted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, segue

I am working on a new application and have used Firebase as a backend various times before. My code (below) is supposed to perform a segue when no user is logged in, do nothing when a 'worker' is logged in, and perform another segue when an 'employer is logged in. This is working fine, but one issue arises. When a 'worker' is signed in and the app is re-run they remain logged in. On the other hand, when an 'employer' logs in the proper segue is performed, but when the app is re-run (I do this so that I can see the console after closing the app), they become logged out and nil is returned as the current user. This signs out the previously logged-in employer. Any help? My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let uid  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let locationReference = ref.child("locations")

    print("CURRENT USER:")
    print(uid)
    print(Auth.auth().currentUser)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        print("SEGUE RAN")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notSignedIn", sender: nil)
    }

    else if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        print("UNO")
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print("DOS")
                let isWorker1 = dictionary["Worker"] as? Bool
                print("IS WORKER:")
                print(isWorker1)
                if isWorker1 == true {
                }
                else if isWorker1 == false {
                    print("TRES")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notWorker", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a off topic comment. Be careful how you're using your if..else statements. For example - in your closure, if isWorker == true then do something, else if isWorker == false do something else, but technically that could fall through and having nothing happen if isWorker is neither true nor false. By using `else if` like that, your leaving it open to other options that are undefined. It should just be if { xxxx } else { yyyy } so then all results are captured either in the if or else blocks.

Comment: The context of the question is a bit confusing. It there is no current user logged in, perform a segue. Ok. So if there is a user logged in, a 'worker' and then you quit the restart the app, they are still logged in. That's correct functionality. But then you mention something about an 'employer' logging in but there's nothing in the code that has anything to do with an 'employer' or than isWorker being false. There's nothing to handle the case where isWorker1 is nil. And there's nothing to show any kind of log out code so we don't know what happens after we know isWorker == false.

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the tip. There is no need to handle isWorker as nil as that will never occur. For clarification, "isWorker = false" means that they are an employer. So, if they are not a worker they are an employer and therefore...

Comment: Your code is stating that it could occur `let isWorker1 = dictionary["Worker"] as? Bool`